# Need some clarification regarding this Qt tutorial, can someone help me out?

Tags: qt

I'm guessing the answers to these questions will be very simple to anyone familiar with Qt. I'm trying to follow this intro tutorial for Qt: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/gettingstartedqt.html. I get it up until the part that I've taken this screenshot for:

http://i160.photobucket.com/albums/t182/thinkpad20/qtintro.jpg

I understand these two code blocks well enough, but if I implement the widget as a class like they show here, what should I be putting in the main function of my code? It doesn't say anywhere. Also, when I try to compile this code, I get a "undefined reference to 'vtable for Notepad'" error. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I guess you need to have some basic knowledge of classes in C++ if you want to follow this tutorial. I'd suggest you start by a C++ class tutorial then move on to the Qt one, then everything will be much clearer.

Comment: The undefined `reference to vtable` can come from not running qmake before compiling. Make sure you clean and then run qmake before building.

Answer (score 3):

`undefined reference to 'vtable for Notepad'` almost certainly means you're not linking in the moc-generated files. The Qt docs mention it as a [common mistake](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html#a-real-example).

As for what to include in `main`, it normally involves the creation of an Application and a GUI element, then calling exec on the application. At its most basic, it might look like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "notepad.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   Notepad mainWindow;
   mainWindow.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```